# How do i remove NONREF and RETURN rows from my CSV output

Tags: linux, awk

i have a csv file which contains rows that has NONREF and RETURN in it, the NONREF rows has already been removed, just need help remove the RETURN rows.

This is what the CSV file look like below:

```
806185341,1395290,29/10/2019,USD,-1743.01
806185341,190944,29/10/2019,USD,-386.75
806185341,NONREF,29/10/2019,USD,21351.47
806185341,NONREF,30/10/2019,USD,-691430.16
806185341,1395043,30/10/2019,USD,-1021.72 
806185341,RETURN,4/10/2019,USD,12.98
```

Code is:

```
awk -v s1="      " '
     BEGIN{
     FS=","
      }
      {
      gsub(/\r/,"")
    }
    FNR==1{
      print
     next
     }
      $2!~/NONREF/{
      $1=substr($1,1,3)"-"substr($1,4,5)"-"substr($1,length($1))
       $2=sprintf("%010d",$2)
       split($3,array,"/")  
      $3=sprintf("%02d%02d%s",array[2],array[1],substr(array[3],3))
      if($NF~/\.[0-9]$/){
       $NF=$NF"0"
       }
       gsub(/^-|\./,"",$NF)
     $NF=sprintf("%012d",$NF)
      $3=$3 $NF
      print $1 s1 $2,$3
       }
      '  Input_file
```

Expected output:

```
806-18534-1      0001395994 103119000000058658
806-18534-1      0001396080 103119000000115483
806-18534-1      0001395958 103119000000076487
806-18534-1      0001395893 103119000000098132
```

Comment: Please see this link, how to use CODE TAGS on SO https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ignore 2 strings in code in that case try.

```
awk -v s1="      " '
BEGIN{
  FS=","
}
{
  gsub(/\r/,"")
}
$2!~/NONREF/ && $2 !~ /RETURN/{
  $1=substr($1,1,3)"-"substr($1,4,5)"-"substr($1,length($1))
  $2=sprintf("%010d",$2)
  split($3,array,"/")  
  $3=sprintf("%02d%02d%s",array[2],array[1],substr(array[3],3))
  if($NF~/\.[0-9]$/){
    $NF=$NF"0"
  }
  gsub(/^-|\./,"",$NF)
  $NF=sprintf("%012d",$NF)
  $3=$3 $NF
  print $1 s1 $2,$3
}
'  Input_file
```

***Few points to be noted:***

- Try to keep indentation of code same like how you get it, else it is very difficult to understand the code.
- I have removed `FNR==1` part from your code since you DO NOT have any heading in your samples in case you have it add it back then.

Comment: @jaybiano, Your welcome.  Please read this link once https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks this will let you know how to use CODE TAGS on Stack overflow. Also please try to keep indentation of your samples and codes in readable manner and it will help all to understand your question more clearly.

Comment: hi @RavinderSingh13 i posted a question about http post request can you help me take a look? that is the link below `` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58775494/my-http-post-request-does-not-work-on-vscode ``

Comment: @jaybiano,sorry I am not sure about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add a `grep` at the end, like:

```
... | grep -v "NONRETURN" | grep -v "NOREF"
```

Comment: Why two greps? `grep -Ev 'NONRETURN|NOREF'`